# Как проверять почту в телеграмм боте

Tags: python, telegram-bot, telegram, telebot

Нужно, чтобы после ввода почты бот проверял есть ли в ней @.
Как это реализовать?
Библиотека: pytelegrambotapi
Телеграмм бот.Заранее спасибо

Comment: регулярные выражения, find, if  "@" in email - это первое что приходит в голову

Answer (score 1):

Мы можем проверить правильность ввода почты с помощью регулярного выражения `([a-z0-9]+[_a-z0-9\.-]*[a-z0-9]+)@([a-z0-9-]+(?:\.[a-z0-9-]+)*\.[a-z]{2,4})`
(Это выражение проверит не только наличие @)

Comment: а что еще он проверяет?

Comment: Мы проверяем символы до и после @, также после @ должна быть точка.